# Add Links block to view's page, below filter, in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, view, block, sidebar

I have this view with a *Page* display that has a filter and a list with content to be filtered.

I would like to add a *Links block* right below the filters form but I just don't get it how. I tried adding the block to the sidebars (from */structure/block*) but the sidebars are outside the main content (Bootstrap theme) and the *View* edit form (*views/view/myview/edit*) has no option or place where I could add a Builder block.

How would you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup the view as block display(or duplicate the page display as block display) and go with the option "Exposed form in block" = Yes in the Advanced section.
It will let you to show the main view block (content list) and the exposed form(filters) in different configurable blocks in any basic/blank page.
Then you can easily insert your links block in between them.

Comment: I did this with 2 views that have different filter fields and both show the same filter

Comment: I found the problem. The filter blocks had to be restricted to their corresponding pages

Comment: Great! I am glad it helped